# How to free array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, free

I am having a problem with freeing array of strings.
I have a program but I made this simple code to see the error:

```
char *cardsName[2];
cardsName[0] = new char[3];
cardsName[0] = "a";
cardsName[1] = new char[3];
cardsName[1] = "c";
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    delete(cardsName[i]);
```

This giving me error `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x080489b8 ***`

and this also giving me error:

```
char *cardsName[2];
cardsName[0] = new char[3];
cardsName[0] = "a";
cardsName[1] = new char[3];
cardsName[1] = "c";
delete []cardsName;
```

free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfc38dd8 ***

Then how I do free for array of pointers to char,... I really need it for my program and I really searched a lot and I can't find solution for this simple problem.

Comment: Your C++ code looks a lot like C code. Have you considered using standard library classes, e.g. `std::array` and `std::string`?

Comment: i have a homework in c++ (I just started the course) in the hw its not allowed to use STL classes etc.. and this is just part of the code without the includes

Comment: Strange how many C++ courses disallow the best parts of C++...

Comment: Not allowed at this part to use string at all (xD) first week of the course is programmed to give work with array of pointers etc..

Comment: @Saif _" ... first week of the course is programmed to give work with array of pointers ..."_ This should be done in the courses advanced sections, not for beginners. Sigh!

Comment: They *should* teach you to *avoid* arrays and pointers.

Comment: I am not beginner, i done C and Java and now i am doing cpp, actually after 3 months of java i almost forget all the dynamic allocation.. i was in love with garbage collector in java

Comment: @Saif _"...  i done C ..."_ I doubt a bit you've really _done_ it. In this case all that stuff should be _bread and butter_ for you, the only difference is using `malloc()` and `free()` instead of `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Comment: to be honest we didn't learnt delete at all on C, only free, and i done it like before 1 year not this year, if i know i wouldn't remember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
cardsName[0] = "a";
```

assigns a pointer to the string literal `"a"`, which can't be deleted. The pointer you have allocated with `cardsName[0] = new char[3];` is discarded, and you will suffer from a memory leak.

You probably meant to use `strncpy()` to assign the value:

```
strncpy("a",cardsname[0],3);
```

---

The second problem is, that

```
delete []cardsName;
```

is also wrong. You never allocated this array with `new[]` thus the statement fails.

Comment: Yes i ment strcpy probably

Comment: @Saif Extended in my answer.

Comment: I didn't get why cardsName[0] = "a"; cant be deleted, but with strcpy it worked but can you explain why? thanks

Comment: @Saif `"a"` is a `char*`  pointer itself, that points to an object with static storage duration (the string literal),  thus it can't be deleted. The `strcpy()` copies the character values from the string literal, to your pointer that was formerly created with `new char[3];`.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  ok i got it, but if i have int *arr[]; what whould be the soultion?, because then i don't have strcpy or function to copy them

Comment: @Saif _"...  but if i have int `*arr[];`... "_ In this case you can actually copy an integer literal by simply dereferencing the pointer: `*(arr[0]) = 5;`. Character string literals are a bit of special case, compared to other primitive type literals.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an array of string, because you only use `char* cardsName` - which is a string(array of chars). If you want to make an array of string, you need to use array of arrays of chars - `char** cardsName`.

Also, instead using naked pointers and `char` arrays you should use `std::string` and `std::vector`/`std::array`.

Comment: yes array of char pointers, string would be more right but its not allowed to be done in this question

Comment: @Fireho To cite from OP's comments: _"in the hw its not allowed to use STL classes etc.. ..."_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That was a suggestion for future. I provided a right answer about this case anyway.

Comment: @Fireho Right answer for what? Why the deletion fails, or is it just a nitpick about calling a `char*` a _string_?